# Javascript async instantiation and private constructor

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, constructor, factory, private

I need to instantiate an object asynchronously. But the constructor method cannot be declared async `async constructor(){}` and be called like so `async new MyClass()`. That would be strange anyway. Therefore, some kind of factory is needed. I also want to hide the constructor. This would be very easy to achieve if the constructor could be declared private: `#constructor`. But even with ES2022 private class features this is not possible. However, there are several patterns to solve these two problems. I will list 3 of them (in the context of ES6 modules).

I would like to know which pattern, if any, are considered good and which are not. Or if there are even better solutions, please let me know.

**Method I:** static boolean (without a factory)

```js
let calledInit = false;

export default class MyClass {
    constructor(data) {
        if (calledInit === false)
            throw Error('private constructor');
        calledInit = false;
        // member initializations here
    }

    static async initialize() {
        calledInit = true;
        // do some async stuff here
        return new MyClass(data);
    }
}
```

**Method II:** closure and singleton-factory

```js
const MyClass = (function() {
    class MyClass {
        constructor(data) {
            // member initializations here
        }
    }

    return {
        initialize: async function() {
            // do some async stuff here
            return new MyClass(data);
        }
    }    
})();
Object.freeze(MyClass);
export default MyClass;
```

use them both like so:

```js
const obj = await MyClass.initialize();
```

**Method III:** factory function

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(data) {
        // member initializations here
    }
}

export default async function MyClassInitializer() {
    // do some async stuff here
    return new MyClass(data);
}
```

use it like so:

```js
const obj = await MyClassInitializer();
```

Edit: To clarify, I believe hiding the constructor is beneficial. Mainly for debugging purpose. Let's say the constructor is public and someone else is instantiating the object using the new operator. It always fails with obscure error messages and she/he can't make sense of it. All this, because she/he didn't carefully read the docs which clearly states to use the initialize() method to create an instance. This could easily have been prevented by hiding the constructor in the first place.

Comment: "*I also want to hide the constructor*" - why?

Comment: Of the three snippets you've show, method III seems preferable for its simplicity. There's no reason though why you wouldn't also export `MyClass` itself, it might come in handy e.g. for tests.

Comment: Hiding the constructor could be preferable for debugging purpose, in my opinion. Since the constructor depends on async data, calling the constructor directly might result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*depends on async data*"? All the data that a constructor depends on should be passed as a parameter (which is lacking in all your snippets, not sure if you just oversimplified them). Whether that data was loaded asynchronously or not shouldn't matter, as long as the data itself is what the constructor expects.

Comment: I personally also prefer method III. The only 'drawback' is that MyClass cannot provide any static method without exposing the constructor eg. exporting MyClass.

Comment: If you're using modules, named exports are as good as static methods (if not better). But really, there's nothing wrong with exporting the whole class when the constructor validates its parameters and throws an exception when called without the data.

Comment: Yes, I oversimplified the code examples. By "depends on async data" I mean that, let's say method MyClassInitializer connects to a WebSocket or a REST API, the resulting data is then passed as parameter to the constructor of MyClass. Edit: I added a parameter to make it more clear.

Comment: Here is an example (Typescript) that illustrates my need: https://dev.to/somedood/the-proper-way-to-write-async-constructors-in-javascript-1o8c

Comment: Method 3 is the correct one.

I do not think it is a good reason to hide the constructor. You wait on async data. Sometimes it might be cached and you do not need the initialize. Then you can call the constructor directly. Further your constructor requires the data as an argument. Nobody is going to call it without knowing what data to pass to it. If you want to do some asynchronous side effects, that is not really a good practice to do in the constructor.

Comment: "*instantiating the object using the `new` operator always fails with obscure error messages*" - then fix that problem by providing proper error messages when the constructor is called with no data or data in the wrong format, instead of just hiding the constructor. You know, your web socket or REST api might provide the wrong data or a different format in some time, and you'll be glad about this yourself. Besides, not exporting the class doesn't exactly make the constructor private anyway, one might still attempt to clone an instance by doing `new instance.constructor(…)`.

Comment: @ArwedMett At least we all agree method 3 is the best one :) I would argue that it actually is bad practice to be able to instantiate an object with both new and a factory.

Comment: @ArwedMett Could you please provide some code example of what you described? Let's assume this: A class that connects to a WebSocket and subscribes to a service/channel. All I need to provide is some kind of subscription information (for the send function) and a callback to receive some data of that service. I don't need to know the WebSocket URL, it's hardcoded inside the class. Every instance of this class will connect to the same WebSocket but may subscribe to different services/channels.

Comment: I think the scenario you describe is should be handled in a function or method of some kind of runtime. You should make the websocket connection and pass it to the class. This way you are also more modular.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer** This is my opinion

Instantiating an object asynchronously is not really a thing for a good reason.

The purpose of the constructor is to construct your object.
You should not put something like load operations from a file, API etc. in the constructor.

Put them into a separate function and use the result as an argument to your class.

```
async () => {
    const data = await fetch(...) // get data / do some sideeffect

    const myObject = new MyObject(data)
}
```

This is also usually desirable since you can update some state to track the progress of the request. Or you might want to cache it and use it in multiple places.

```
async () => {

    state = "LOADING"
    const data = await fetch(...) // get data / do some sideeffect

    state = "SUCCESS"

    const myObject = new MyObject(data)
}
```

Hiding the constructor is not really needed since you get an error when you do not pass data to it. And the user of your class should know what to pass. If you use typescript, this would be even more strict.

Sure you can put this in one initialize function as in method 3.

Comment: I totally agree that async/loading operations should kept separate from constructing. I asked a related question with a specific example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73183256/websocket-static-methods-vs-instance-methods