# WebSocket static methods vs instance methods

Tags: javascript, api, design-patterns, websocket, static

I need a module that handles connections and subscriptions to one or more specified WebSockets (URLs are hardcoded inside the module). The module provides various methods to interact with these WebSockets and also REST APIs associated with these WebSockets. It should only establish a connection when there's a request and close when the WebSockets are not needed anymore. Any part of the app can import this module and connect to the WebSockets/endpoints. But it never exposes the WebSocket instances.

This question is not about the inner workings of the module, but about the API. I see two main ways to create the interface: Through static methods (individually exported functions) or through instancing a class that provides those methods.

Both ways have pros and cons. However, I would argue that it doesn't make much sense to create a class with methods that references these WebSockets, since the WebSockets are static by definition (they're declared at the top level of the module, outside any function definitions). This just adds an unnecessary layer of complexity, it's basically a proxi to the static methods. The only benefit I see in creating an instance is that the connection is guaranteed before interacting with the WebSocket in question (see code example below).

I'm interested in your experience and opinion.

The examples should illustrate how these modules could be used. I've coded both and both work. But still not quite sure which is best.

Static methods:

```js
// Import all the functions
import * as SpecificWebSocketManager from 'specific-websocket-manager.js';

// Subscribing to the private WebSocket requires an authentication token
const token = await SpecificWebSocketManager.getWebSocketToken({ apikey: 'string', secret: 'string' });

// Any private subscription requires this token along with other informations 
// Different api keys can be used with the same WebSocket 
const subscription = {
    token: 'string',  
    apikey: 'string', 
    name: 'subscriptionName', 
    callback: subscriptionCallback,
};

// The manager establishes a connection to the WebSocket 
//     if it has not yet been established. This is an async call 
// This doesn't guarantee that the subscription will be successful, 
//     the connection might fail
SpecificWebSocketManager.subscribe(subscription).catch();

// The manager closes the WebSocket when there are no more subscriptions
SpecificWebSocketManager.unsubscribe(subscription);
```

Instancing:

```js
// Import default
import SpecificWebSocketManager from 'specific-websocket-manager.js';

// The manager establishes a connection to the WebSocket 
//     if it has not yet been established. This is an async call 
// The WebSocket token will be fetched internally if it doesn't exist
// This guarantees that a connection is established if the instance is created
// Note that we anyway need to make a static call to create an instance (factory)
const privateInstance = await SpecificWebSocketManager.privateInstance({ apikey: string, secret: string }).catch(); 

// Apikey is already provided and token already fetched
const subscription = { 
    name: 'subscriptionName',
    callback: subscriptionCallback 
};

// Connection is already established, no async call here
privateInstance.subscribe(subscription);

// The manager keeps the connection alive, even if there are no other subscriptions
//     because I might subscribe again at a later point in time
privateInstance.unsubscribe(subscription);

// The manager only closes the WebSocket if all instances are closed
// This will not allow me to subscribe again
privateInstance.close();

// This will allow me to subscribe again 
privateInstance.connect().catch();
```

Comment: What happens if you call `privateInstance` multiple times?

Comment: It will only instantiate the WebSocket once. The manager adds resolve/reject methods to an array and then calls them when the connection succeeded (onopen) or failed (onerror). This also works if privateInstance is called without await.

Comment: But do you get different instances back or always the same object?

Comment: It returns new instances, but referencing to the same WebSocket instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing several [concerns that should be separated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns):

- the inner workings ("*establish a connection when there's a request and close when the WebSockets are not needed anymore*")
- the configuration which websockets/APIs to use ("*one or more specified WebSockets, URLs are hardcoded inside the module*")
- assuring that there's only a single static instance ("*the WebSockets are static by definition, declared at the top level of the module*")

It may be convenient in ordinary usage to have a singleton with hardcoded configuration, but I would still advise against it. There are several cases where this is inconvenient:

- In testing, you want no global state, you want multiple independent instances, you want to mock the web sockets, and you want to connect to some specific test endpoints instead of the usual production ones
- A user may have multiple different API keys (unusual, but not unthinkable). They need different instances with separate connections.
- As you suggested, the connection (and error handling) pattern is nicer with a factory function that returns a promise for a working instance, instead of the instance having to hide the internal connecting and error handling.

So I would suggest that you do export multiple separate things (possibly even putting the code in separate modules):

- a `class` with the inner logic, taking all configuration (and possibly the successfully connected websockets) as parameters to the constructor
- a setup/initialisation function that does the connection setup, returning a working instance, taking all configuration as parameters
- the default configuration that can be passed to the setup function (or alternatively, just another function with default parameter values)
- a storage object that can be used to lookup/cache shared instances with the same overall configuration, or shared websockets with the same url and token (depending on what exactly you need)
- a `getInstance()` function that implements the singleton pattern, if this is the standard usage pattern for your library. It should not take any parameters, configuration like the API keys should be read from global variables or environment variables.
  Or alternatively, instead of a getter function just default-export the singleton instance directly, if it is cheap to set up (does not require lazy initialisation)

Comment: In my example I considered different API keys. But why are multiple connections needed? Communication can be done through the same WebSocket despite different keys.

Comment: Ah ok then you really need only one socket per endpoint. But I don't know how your communication protocol works and how it handles errors, you'd need to be pretty certain that all messages are completely independent from each other and only will be received by the instance that they were meant for. Multiple connections might be needed (wanted) if you were to test just this behaviour, or in general to ensure that one connection (failure, latency, flow control, etc) does not affect the other. It might be unnecessary in standard use cases, but separating this out gives you more flexibility.

Comment: The subscriptions are stored like so `{ apikey: { subscriptionName: Set<callbacks> }}`. I can address the instances individually. It's still unclear to me how the api would look like the separation, as you described, is respected. Could you please provide some dummy code?

Comment: So every message on the web socket contain, even possible error messages, contains an api key and a subscription name so that you know which callbacks to notify?

Comment: yes, callbacks (or instances) can be addressed individually.

Comment: I think there are are many degrees in separations of concerns. I usually work backwards when designing my classes/apis, asking myself, how I want to use this thing in the most simplest and abstract way. I chose a very high level of abstraction in this particular problem. My only concern is 'hey, I just want to get notified when something happens (subscription) or request other informations (REST). I don't really care about configurations (layer of abstraction) because I already know what endpoint I'm connecting to'.

Comment: Sure, you can always say that [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) :-) But you asked for a good API design / code structure, and that should offer flexibility through dependency injection. The simple high-level "don't care about configurations" function should still be available, and even be the default main entry point, but the lower-level parts that accept more detailed options should be offered in addition to that, and your code should be built from the beginning to support this kind of usage when necessary.

Comment: To be very explicit, I'm trying to create my own library that connects to Kraken's REST and WebSocket API. There are already libraries out there (https://github.com/nothingisdead/npm-kraken-api/tree/a7c5dbd7983a964aa91bd6391e273856cc71628a), but they only support REST API calls. I want mine to support WebSockets as well. If you look at their API, the only parameters they use for instantiation is an Api key and a secret. The API URL is also hidden inside the module. In that logic, I also want to keep my WebSocket URLs inside the module. No other configurations are needed, really.

Comment: 1/2  Another reason why I was trying a static approach is because I'm recently experimenting with data-oriented programming (separating data from code, not to be confused with [data-oriented design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design).

Trying to apply this paradigm, all that WebSockets or a REST call are doing is generating data or sending data, but they do not transform the data. The only difference between REST and a WebSocket is that a WebSocket generates a continuous stream of data.

Comment: 2/2  Although a WebSocket does have an internal state (connecting, open, etc.), the resulting state is always 'open' and nothing will/should mess with this state during the lifetime of the app. So it still can be thought of as stateless because it will always produce the same data once it's up and running, and again the state will not mess with the data.

And everything that does not have an internal state can be thought of as static, which means no instance of some sort is required. Therefore, the module exposes static methods only. But maybe that's the wrong way I think about it.